# Merge two lines into one picking selected words from both

Tags: awk, sed

I need to convert file1 is such way that it has three words in each line, where first is second word from line starting with **'ROBO'** and second word is second word from line starting with **'1)'** and finally third word is fourth word from from line starting with **'1)'**. See example below...

```
$cat file1
ROBO lab1 - Topology:
1) 10.195.41.1          10.195.41.255        comment1         
ROBO lab2 - Topology:
1) 10.95.4.1            10.95.4.254          comment2
```

to :

```
lab1 10.195.41.1 comment1
lab2 10.95.4.1 comment2
```

I ended up with the following:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' file1| awk '{ if ($6 ~ /^10\./) print $2 " " $6}'
```

but it breaks when I have something like this:

```
ROBO lab1 - Topology:
ROBO lab1 - Topology:
1) 10.195.41.1          10.195.41.255        comment1         
ROBO lab2 - Topology:
1) 10.95.4.1
```

I need to control that first line starts with **'ROBO'** and second starts with **'1)'** and move down the file if not..until I meet the right pair

Comment: Could the comment be several words?

Comment: Are the `1)`-lines tab separated?

Comment: Comment could be several words, there is space after '1)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '/^ROBO/ { n = $2 } /^1\)/ { $1 = n; $3 = ""; print }' file1
lab1  10.195.41.1  comment1
lab2  10.95.4.1  comment2
```

This works as expected, but will contract any consecutive spaces in the comments.

The first part extracts the second word on any `ROBO` line.

The second part will replace the first input field of any `1)` line with the word from the most recent `ROBO` line and empty the third input field before printing the modified record.

For the second set of example input, this produces

```
lab1 10.195.41.1  comment1
lab2 10.95.4.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply with ***awk***:

> "... convert file1 in such way that it has **three** words in each line ..."

```
awk '/^ROBO/{ printf "%s ",$2  }/^1\)/{ printf "%s %s\n",$2,$4 }' file1
```

The output:

```
lab1 10.195.41.1 comment1
lab2 10.95.4.1 comment2
```

Comment: @Kusalananda, I've intentionally added the OP's condition/citation about **three** words. So 3 words means 3 words. Otherwise the question should be elaborated